# Microsoft Graph: How to filter users by domain name

Tags: azure, microsoft-graph-api

A tenant can have multiple assigned domains and all users are directly organized within a tenant. To get a list of all users you could simply ask:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users
```

But I'd like to filter the list by the used domain within the user principal name. After reading the [explanation at MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/ad/graph/howto/azure-ad-graph-api-supported-queries-filters-and-paging-options) and the [developer documentation](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/query_parameters) it seems that it is not possible to do something like this.

You can only check for (not) equality or if a string starts with some text, but it is not possible to check if a string ends with something specific.

I wish there would exists something like, but neither is:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users?$filter=endsWith(userPrincipalName, 'mydomain.com')
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users?$filter=userPrincipalName eq '*@mydomain.com'
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users?$filter=userPrincipalName eq '.*@mydomain.com$'
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users?$filter=domain eq 'mydomain.com'
```

Does anyone have an idea on how to filter the list of users for a specific domain?

Comment: If the API refuses to do the endswith filter, then probably the only way is to do the filtering client-side.

Comment: @juunas: Yes, that's what I'm currently doing, but it doesn't make sense to download dozen of users just to throw them away. And it seems to be such a simple requirement that I really can't understand why it is not supported.

Comment: Perf reasons? Index is ordered in ascending order? The query would be very expensive for them?

Comment: Not performance, but if you have a tenant with 1000 users, split up into two domains and always request all users, just to throw away fifty percent just feels dirty. I have all informations and I simply prefer to make any filtering as near as possible to the source.

Comment: Hi Oliver, please also post a feature request at [User Voice - Microsoft Graph/O365 REST APIs](https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-general/filters/new?category_id=101632), Microsoft Graph team will review them frequently.

Comment: @HongboMiao: It's already been there: [OData filter 'contains'](https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-feature-requests-and-feedback/suggestions/17278982-odata-filter-contains) and [Allow MS Graph proxyAddress filters to specify endsWith() and contains()](https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-feature-requests-and-feedback/suggestions/31838047-allow-ms-graph-proxyaddress-filters-to-specify-end) I upvoted both.

Comment: @Oliver Cooool!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

endsWith is working since recently.

Graph explorer example:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0//users?$count=true&$filter=endsWith(userPrincipalName,'@example.com')&$select=id,userPrincipalName
```

Graph.NET SDK:

```
var request = graphServiceClient.Users
                .Request()
                .Header("ConsistencyLevel", "eventual")
                .Filter("endswith(userPrincipalName,'@example.com')")
                .Select(x => new { x.Id, x.UserPrincipalName })
                .OrderBy("userPrincipalName");
request.QueryOptions.Add(new QueryOption("$count", "true"));

var result = await request.GetAsync();
```

See also example 5 at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-list?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=csharp (at this moment the C# example in the docs is incomplete)

Comment: Great to hear. Thanks for the update. Now `contains` is the only missing one. But I remember, that I made a deeper dive when I asked that questions (wow, already three years now) and that `contains` is something that will *never* be supported by the underlying architecture. But maybe some shiny day, how knows. ;-)

Answer (score 3):

Microsoft Graph doesn't support `endsWith` or `contains` at this time.

If this is something you expect to search on regularly, you could add a [Schema Extension](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/resources/schemaextension) that targets `user` resources to hold the user's email domain.

While the initial population would be work intensive, maintaining it over time could be managed by [tracking changes to users](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/delta_query_users) via the `/delta` endpoint. You could periodically pull a `/delta` and update only the affected `user` resources.

Comment: Thanks for the additional ideas. I'm already inspecting the schema extension, and tried to create one. After some digging and trying with the graph explorer I found that statement: "Also you CANNOT currently create a schema extension definition (or manage it) through Graph Explorer. For you to created a definition, you must either be an admin or the owner of the app creating the extension definition AND the creation request must also come from that application (which cannot be graph explorer). We may look at relaxing this last constraint." You should REALLY relax this thing.